# Access data in spool from browser

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

How to access the spool before sending emails.

I am using swiftmailer with symfony2.

in my setting,

mail data is stored once in app/spool/***.message
then if I do command like this , mail data stored here will be sent.

```
sudo php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

However I would like to check the email data before sending.

I can see the content of each mails directly from shell, however

I would like to check the email data from the browser.

How can I access to the spool data from php or twig???

Comment: I don't find anything already implemented on this topic. You can write your custom `queueReader`  by taking a look at this: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/FileSpool.php#L141 hope this help

Comment: Thanks I see, it could be the good reference. I will try to implement by myself

Comment: Hi @whitebear can be a very interesting project, consider to opensource it!